# Forcing a wireframing font to justify

Tags: fonts, justification

[The libre font `Redacted`](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Redacted?query=Redacted)  has a nice look for visualising the wireframing of a text heavy document.  However, in LaTeX, I can't seem to get it to justify, and I'm not quite sure why.  The code below, as seen, produces non-justified line endings, and playing around with `hyphenpenalty` and `emergencystretch` did not produce meaningfully different results as it would with other types:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Redacted}
\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: as far as I can see it's being treated as a monospace font so gets no flexibility in the white space, you would see similar setting with `\ttfamily`

Comment: The font sets the space metrics to 0 hence TeX cannot justify the text.